# Entity Framework many to many relationship Delete

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class that is called User. It has a property called Roles. Each user has many roles and each role can be assigned to many users.

The relationship is established by a 3rd table. I'd like to be able to remove a role from a User. However, I am calling the database twice. Once to **fully** load the "User" role and once to delte the role.

```
var user =  this.Users.Include(f => f.Roles)
                  .SingleOrDefault(f => f.CustomerID == customerId && f.UserID == userId);
  if (user != null)
  {
    var role = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault(f => f.RoleID == roleId);
    if (role != null)
    {
      user.Roles.Remove(role);
      return this.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
  }
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

```
var user = new User { CustomerID = customerId, UserID = userId };
this.Users.Attach(user);

var role = new Role { RoleID = roleId };
this.Roles.Attach(role);

user.Roles.Add(role);
user.Roles.Remove(role);

return this.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

My Context has a `DbSet<User>` and `DbSet<Role>`. I don't have one for UserRole and I don't intend to have it.

Am i doing it right and do I need to always do 2 database calls?

-- User Class

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "urn:AES/Schemas/2014/09", IsReference = true)]
  public class User
  {
    .....

    [DataMember]
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
  }
```

The Mapping

```
 this.HasMany(u => u.Roles)
  .WithMany()
  .Map(m =>
    {
      // The "left" key is the one specified in the HasMany method; the "right" key is the one specified in the WithMany method.
      m.MapLeftKey(new string[] { "CustomerID", "UserID" });
      m.MapRightKey("RoleID");
      m.ToTable("UserRoles");
    }
  );

  // Table & Column Mappings
  this.ToTable("Users");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious why you don't model those other tables like `UserRoles`, are you just lazy?  =)

But seriously, what you're doing is fine however for mass deletes EF doesn't have a bulk delete capability, you are better off simply executing the `DELETE` statement directly, like this:

```
using (System.Data.Common.DbCommand cmd = Context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
  cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM Table WHERE KeyColumn = @Id";
  YourSqlHelper.AddParameter(cmd, "@Id", id);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: This would work T Mckeown. Is there any other way besides embedding SQL becasue that defeats the point of using Entity Framework.

Comment: EF isn't a cure all, it's an abstraction layer for the DB, it's main purpose is for CRUD operations and SELECT